# UVa 12921 ( Triple Shots Help )

Tags: geometry

Please watch this problem .

Link : https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=862&page=show_problem&problem=4800

I have been trying to solve this Geometry problem from a few Weeks ago . But every time I failed . My approach to solve this problem is ---

As 3 points are in same distance that simply means The point we will found in the result that will be a Center of a Circle whose radius is The distance of those 3 points distinctly. Let 3 points are ( x1, y1, x2, y2, x3 , y3 ). SO , we can write,

```
(x1 - H)^2 + (y1 - K)^2 = (x2 - H)^2 + (y2 - K)^2 
=> (x1^2 + y1^2 -x2^2 -y2^2) - 2H(x1-x2) - 2K(y1-y2) = 0
=> A - 2HX1 - 2KY1 = 0  ------ ( i )

 (x2 - H)^2 + (y2 - K)^2 = (x3 - H)^2 + (y3 - K)^2 
 => (x2^2 + y2^2 -x3^2 -y3^2) - 2H(x2-x3) - 2K(y2-y3) = 0
 => B - 2HX2 - 2KY2 = 0 ------- ( ii )
```

And then we can Solute this two equation in the following way :

So,

```
    A - 2HX1 - ( (B - 2HX2) / Y2 ) * Y1 = 0  [ Putting the value of 2K from eqn ( ii ) ]
=>  H = ( AY2 - BY1 ) / ( 2 * ( X1Y2 - X2Y1 ) ) ----- (iii)
And,
=>  K = ( B - 2HX2 ) / 2Y2   ----- ( iv )
```

Now , if those points are previously Co-Linear then I will print " Impossible " . But If not then we will do the above's Calculation . If ( H, K ) are in the same distance from those 3 points ( x1, y1, x2, y2, x3 , y3 ) the Print ( H, K ) else print " Impossible ".

Is my approach correct ( My code give answers " Impossible " for all test. ) ? If not then why ? Give me some Idea that how can I solve it ?? Thanks in Advance .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about a practical programming related problem as described in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: When an user tried s lot but didn't find how to Solve a problem ... Then he finds help from this type of Site .. If they find their help they will be very pleased . But you moderator guys are Showing your powers Closing Them ... Then the users lost Hope to ask for help .. Because they always in a Frightened mind as their Topic is gonna closed or they will get Negative Rating for this post .. After a while they will not be able to post any question for a huge number of Negative Ratings... Really you moderator's are great @Jongware

Comment: Equal distance to three given points means your ship is in the center of the circumcircle through these three points, which in turn means you'll just have to intersect two perpendicular bisectors. Your formulas look far more complicated than that. So far, there is nothing programming-related about this yet, so closing the question as off-topic seems appropriate. If you have any serious trouble finding a formula for the circumcenter, you may ask on [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/), but make sure you format what you have in a more readable way there (using TeX formatting for math).

Comment: I am not a moderator. Moderators leave Close Voting to common users, and rarely use their powers to interfere in the daily business. Did you read the help page I linked to? Probably not. You did not even take the suggestion of [reading the introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) when signing in on Stack Overflow (yes, even common users such as me can see that).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is a little complex.

A general form of a circle is
`x^2 + y^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0`.
In this way, you can avoid the square for variables.

Given 3 points, you can solve D, E, and F replacing x and y by those points. (The coefficient of F is always 1 so you can solve D and E quickly using [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule), subtracting one equation from the other.)

When you get D & E, the coordinate of the center is `(-D/2, -E/2)`. (So you can just ignore the F in the last step.) Note that when D or E is infinite, then it's impossible to find a center for that case.